# Change MainWindow content on QT

Tags: c++, qt, window

I'm newbie in QT. I'm following some videos and decided to do something by myself.

The idea is that the first screen asks for the user to put the password, if it matches I would like to change the content of the same window to something different.

I know how to create a new window but I can't change the current one. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [QWizard](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwizard.html) is probably one of the most suited classes if you intend to change your window contents *as a sequence of pages* (`QWizardPage`s)

A second famous alternative: [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html) which displays only one widget at a time in a stack fashion.